# grab one element instead of all

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have areas in my html, that have unique `href='#cha'`, cha is unique and different for every area. I need to grab area on click in my js, i have already this unique value.
valueRegionSelect contains my unique value on click(it's change depends on my click, for example klu, chu, ada, etc.).

html part with my areas:

```
<div class="b-map">

    <div class="b-map__city"></div>

    <div class="b-map__item">
        <img class="mapImage" src="/images/map-light.png" width="701" height="408" border="0" usemap="#map" />

        <map name="map">
            <area shape="poly" coords="615,0,554,20,548,87,558," title="<?php echo isset($this->region['chu']) ? $this->region['chu']['r_name'] : "region name for  chu" ?>" href="#chu" />
            <area shape="poly" coords="47,237,63,237,67,246,48,248" title="<?php echo isset($this->region['klu']) ? $this->region['klu']['r_name'] : "region name for  klu" ?>" href="#klu" />
```

this one grab all areas, but i need only one area with selected unique element:

```
$mapItem = $('.b-map__item area');
```

I use it in same function in js:

```
coords = $mapItem.attr('coords').split(','),
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you add the final HTML that your code outputs?

Comment: `$mapItem = $('.b-map__item').find('area[href="#cha"]');`

Comment: `$mapItem = $('.b-map__item').find('area[href="#'+valueRegionSelect+'"]');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the `<area>` with a specific `href`, then use the attribute selector:

```
var valueRegionSelect = "cha";
$mapItem = $('.b-map__item').find('area[href="#' + valueRegionSelect + '"]');
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

( http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ )

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly then this should work

```
var areaHref = ('#yourselectId').val();
$mapItem = $('.b-map__item').find('area[href="#'+areaHref+'"]'); ;
```

Comment: $mapItem = $('.b-map__item').find('area[href="#'+valueRegionSelect+'"]');